# Converting DistanceToSphere to DistanceSquaredToSphere

Tags: c++, optimization, distance, collision

I have a small function that returns the distance from a sphere to a line.  Fundamentally, it's just:

```
return Distance(sphereCenter,closestPointOnLine) - sphereRadius;
```

Very simple.  HOWEVER, I want to get rid of the sqrt when measuring the distance, and make it distancesquared.  This doesn't work because of the subtraction... i.e, both of these return wrong values:

```
return DistanceSquared(sphereCenter,closestPointOnLine) - sphereRadius; // Obviously invalid
return DistanceSquared(sphereCenter,closestPointOnLine) - sphereRadius*sphereRadius; // Exponentially wrong
```

My question: IS there any mathematical trick or technique that would allow me to do this?

(Edit: For clarity I understand that "mathematically" there's no way to do this that isn't computationally expensive... what I'm looking for is some kind of trick or way that programmers turn logic on its head to get the desired result in a nonintuitive way)

Comment: Since this is really more math-related that programming related, you could perhaps get better help on [the math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: I thought it must be a very common need in doing 3d graphics on a computer... often the math exchange people reply with a blackboard full of equations with sigmas in them that forces a crash course in vector calculus to turn it into code!

Comment: Well, your measurement is: `(r+d)^2 = r^2 + d^2 + 2rd`, so if you subtract your radius squared, you are left with `d^2+2rd`, which is a quadratic equation to solve, and doesn't seem numerically faster.

Comment: Cross-domain research is like that. You ask the math people, they give you a crazy equation, and then you transfer it into the programming domain. We're here to help with the second part.

Comment: @pptaszni Hm... I understand this.  It's not really a "math" question though because what I was hoping for was that someone had developed a trick to get those components out, or reverse the logic of the if statement, or something like that.  What I really want to do is say if (DistanceSquaredFromSphereToLine < somevalueSquared) then branch.

Comment: Well OK, actually assuming your radius is constant, this might (or might not) be faster: [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%7Bx%2B+r%5E2+%2B+2*r*sqrt%5Bx%5D+-+y%7D%2C+x%5D) x is what you look for, y is your `DistanceSquared(sphereCenter,closestPointOnLine)`. Then you do: multiplication, square root, addition.